# Stream data into Azure Databricks using Event Hubs

Tags: azure, stream, databricks

I want to send messages from a Twitter application to an Azure event hub. However, I am getting the an error that says instead of `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` use 
    `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService`.

I do not know how to create the EventHubClient.create now. Please help.

I am referring to code from the link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-databricks/databricks-stream-from-eventhubs

This is error I am getting:

> notebook:15: error: type mismatch; found :
>   `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` required:
>   `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService`
>
> ```
> val pool = `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)`
>
> val eventHubClient = EventHubClient.create(connStr.toString(), pool)
> ```

Here is my code,

```
import java.util._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs._
import java.util.concurrent.{Executors, ExecutorService}

val pool: ExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)
val eventHubClient = EventHubClient.create(connStr.toString(), pool)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a library in your Databricks workspace using the Maven coordinates `com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11:2.3.2` or higher version.
Attach the created library to your cluster and re-attach the notebook to your cluster after it.

```
import java.util._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs._
import java.util.concurrent._
//Set up Connection to Azure Event Hubs
val namespaceName = "namespaceName_of_event_hub"
val eventHubName = "Name_of_event_hub"
val sasKeyName = "your_Sas_key_name"
val sasKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
val connStr = new ConnectionStringBuilder()
            .setNamespaceName(namespaceName)
            .setEventHubName(eventHubName)
            .setSasKeyName(sasKeyName)
            .setSasKey(sasKey)
val pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)
val eventHubClient = EventHubClient.create(connStr.toString(), pool)
```

Comment: Yes, After doing above steps I am able to resolve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: However, I am getting error, when calling below method, it's failing at line "eventHubClient.get().send(messageData)"

def sendEvent(message: String) = {
  val messageData = EventData.create(message.getBytes("UTF-8"))
  println(messageData)
  eventHubClient.get().send(messageData)
  System.out.println("Sent event: " + message + "\n")
}

Error I am  getting;
com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.EventHubException: connection aborted
 at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.ExceptionUtil.toException(ExceptionUtil.java:58)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54714707/com-microsoft-azure-eventhubs-eventhubexception-connection-aborted-error