# Scala Notebook Type Mismatch error when creating Event Hub for streaming tweets

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, databricks, azure-eventhub

I want to send messages from a Twitter application to an Azure event hub. However, I am getting an error that says:

```
notebook:20: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
 required: java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService
val eventHubClient = EventHubClient.create(connStr.toString(), pool)
```

I do not know how to create the EventHubClient.create now. Please help.

I am referring to code from the link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-databricks/databricks-stream-from-eventhubs.

Also, I have tried the solution from link:
[Stream data into Azure Databricks using Event Hubs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54693437/stream-data-into-azure-databricks-using-event-hubs) and it doesn't work for me.

The version of the cluster is 5.2 (includes Apache Spark 2.4.0, Scala 2.11) which should include the Java SE 8 libraries that have the new ScheduledExecutorService member. Also, the libraries attached are com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11:2.3.9 and org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.7, so again all the prerequisites are met.

The code is:

```
import java._
import java.util._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs._
import java.util.concurrent._
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService
val pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)
val eventHubClient = EventHubClient.create(connStr.toString(), pool)
```

Comment: Did you try using `val pool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)` instead?

Comment: That really works! Thank you very much!